# python 3 -- optimizing line by line prepend

Tags: python-3.x, prepend

I'm working on a simple data prepend program. I've got a long list (around 15,000) of barcodes on separate lines in a text document. I want to prepend each barcode with a code ('a:' for example). I've created a program that will read the text file, prepend the data, and then write the result to a separate file. Code is:

```
bcodeIn = open('bcode.txt', encoding="utf8")
for line in bcodeIn:
    prepend = "a:"+line

    with open('bcode_prepend.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(prepend)
```

Because of the file's length, is this the best way to go about this? Is there a more efficient way, memory-wise?

Answer (score 1):

One major thing comes to mind, which is that you shouldn't be reopening the output file for every one of your fifteen thousand lines. Swap the loop with the context manager, and you may see a speedup:

```
bcodeIn = open('bcode.txt', encoding="utf8")
with open('bcode_prepend.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in bcodeIn:
        file.write("a:"+line)
```

---

You could also probably improve performance by creating the whole output string (using `join`) and then writing it at once. This would cut down on your string concatenations as well as your number of file writes. My tests suggest that this provides a modest speedup, but if your lines are extremely long or your hardware is limited, your results may differ.

As you specifically asked for "memory-wise" efficiency, I do feel obligated to point out that writing the whole string at once consumes significantly more memory, though probably not enough to be an issue!

As always, there's no real substitute for [testing it](http://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) [yourself](http://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html)!

```
bcodeIn = open('bcode.txt', encoding="utf8")
with open('bcode_prepend.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write('a:')
    file.write('a:'.join(line for line in bcodeIn))
```

---

For posterity, here are my timing results. [As usual](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#String_Concatenation), using `str.join` proves noticeably better than repeated concatenation.

```
>>> import timeit
>>> s = '''import random
... import io
... data = [str(random.randint(0,100)) for _ in range(1000)]
... out = io.StringIO()'''
>>> plus = '''for n in data:
...     out.write('a:'+n)'''
>>> form = '''for n in data:
...     out.write('a:{}'.format(n))'''
>>> join = '''out.write('a:'+('a:'.join(n for n in data)))'''
>>> min(timeit.repeat(plus, s, number=10000, repeat=20))
1.5328539289755554
>>> min(timeit.repeat(form, s, number=10000, repeat=20))
3.371942257764431
>>> min(timeit.repeat(join, s, number=10000, repeat=20))
0.5443316215198593
>>>
```

Comment: Much faster now. Thank you.